# How can I scale kotlin coroutines workers?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to lean about Kotlin coroutines and use them to execute async tasks, currently I have a spring web application where I need to read some files content and insert into a `dynamoDB`.

To speed things up, I tried to read and buffer 25 lines read into a list and to a `batchWrite` into dynamo, also this `batchWrite` I'm doing in an `async` function like this:

```kotlin
val fileData = file.readAllBytes()
val batchSaveList = mutableListOf<ClientDTO>()

fileData.inputStream().bufferedReader()
    .forEach {
        batchSaveList.add(it)
            if (batchSaveList.size == 25) {
                saveClientListAsync(clientRepository, batchSaveList.toList())
                batchSaveList.clear()
        }
    }

private fun saveClientListAsync(
        clientRepository: ClientRepository,
        batchSaveList: MutableList<ClientDTO>
    ) {
        GlobalScope.async {
            launch {
                clientRepository.saveList(hardFilterListBatchSave)
                // The saveList above run a simple dynamoDBMapper.batchSave(hardFilterList)
            }
        }
    }
```

The file I'm reading has ~500_000 lines, grouping them into lists of 25 items to do the `batchWrite` means about ~20_000 calls to `dynamoDB`.

The current behavior is that my code can read all the 500k lines really fast, about a couple minutes, but the async's dynamo saves are really slow, not the dynamo call it self, as I could see it's taking like 15ms each call with the `dynamoDBMapper.batchSave()`, but the application seems to use only 2 workers to process this "async list" which takes about 20 minutes to execute them all.

Is there a way to improve this flow? Maybe scale up the workers somehow? Or there is a better way to do that since looks like `dynamoDB` calls are not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Spring so I can comment only on the parts I recognize.

1. You're doing unnecessary list copies. That can be avoided by iterating a sequence of the lines and using `chunked()`.
2. You're creating nested coroutines for no reason by calling `async` and then calling `launch` inside it. There's no reason to use `aysnc` if you aren't doing anything with the returned result.

Fixing the above issues avoids some unnecessary work, but I don't know if it will be significant in your case.

I don't know if your repo's `saveList` is a blocking write function. If it is, then you should specify `Dispatchers.IO` when you launch the coroutine.

You might also try creating a FileInputStream and reading from that instead of reading all the data up front.

And you might also try batching more than 25 lines at a time--25 seems trivial to me. Try 1000.

```
file.inputStream().bufferedReader()
    .useLines { lineSequence ->
        lineSequence.chunked(1000)
            .forEach { saveClientListAsync(clientRepository, it) }
    }

private fun saveClientListAsync(
        clientRepository: ClientRepository,
        batchSaveList: MutableList<ClientDTO>
    ) {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            clientRepository.saveList(hardFilterListBatchSave)
            // The saveList above run a simple dynamoDBMapper.batchSave(hardFilterList)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Indeed the async/launch was wrong and I changed it to your example already. About the 25 items, it's limited to 25 items since [DynamoDB batchWrite](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html) execution accepts only 25 items max